# ILGenerator: Load created method

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, reflection.emit, intermediate-language

I am using System.Reflection.Emit, and at some point I want to create a delegate from a MethodBuilder:

```
MethodBuilder fooBuilder = createFooMethodBuilder();
ILGenerator ilGenerator = ...
Type delegateType = typeof(DelegateType);
LocalBuilder delegateVar = ilGenerator.DeclareLocal(delegateType);
//Somehow create emit instructions to create delegate from fooBuilder
//Store delegate in delegateVar using
```

I could find out that to create delegates from static functions something like this is used:

```
ldnull 
ldftn void class Test.MainClass::bar()
newobj instance void class Test.DelegateType::'.ctor'(object, native int)
```

But now I'm stuck. I need a way to ldftn the MethodBuilder and then I need a way to emit the instruction for the following line. And I have no idea how to get a constructor that accepts a native int.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Interesting question. If you don't get a solution, you could emit a call to [Delegate.CreateDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `native int` is an `IntPtr` in C#.

You can get the `ConstructorInfo` for the delegate type using `Type.GetConstructor`:

```
var constructorInfo =
    delegateType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(IntPtr) });
```

Then you can emit the IL instructions like this:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldftn, someMethodInfo);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, constructorInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

The ILGenerator class has an Emit overload that takes a methodinfo, so you can do something like `ilGenerator.Emit(Opcodes.ldftn, mi)`, where `mi` is the method you want to call. It can be any method you found with the reflection API, or even another method you created with a MethodBuilder (it derives from `MethodInfo`).

Similarly, to call a constructor you would emit a newobj instruction providing a ConstructorInfo for the target overload.